# how to remote database mysql XAMPP from another computer?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, lan

the script of connection =

```
<?
$server = "192.168.0.167";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "dbbook";
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Koneksi gagal");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database tidak bisa dibuka");
?>
```

and i had add this script on my.cnf file after [mysqld] =

```
bind-address=192.168.0.167
```

but it didnt work with the following caption

> mycomputer.mshome.net is not allowed to connect to this Mysql server

Please help me.How to remote database mysql XAMPP from another computer ?

Comment: can you ping 192.168.0.167 from the webservers ip? 192.168.* is a local network so im guessing you correctly opened the port(3306) in your router/firewall

Comment: i can ping 192.168.0.167

Answer (score 3):

You will have to [create a new user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) in MySQL that is allowed to connect from a remote host.

By default, root can only connect from `localhost`.

You could try running the following commands from the MySQL server (make sure to substitute `192.168.0.99` with the IP or hostname of the PC that will be connecting) **In your case, try `'php'@'mycomputer.mshome.net' for the user`**:

```
CREATE USER 'php'@'192.168.0.99' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbbook.* TO 'php'@'192.168.0.99';
```

It is possible to specify a wildcard host (`'php'@'%'`), but then if anyone got your MySQL password they could connect to the DB.  You could also wildcard your subnet (`'php'@'192.168.0.%')` which is a little safer.

Comment: it didnt work. the following caption `mycomputer.mshome.net is not allowed to connect to this Mysql server`. I had create user with alnergisaver name, Please help :(

Comment: Ok, try `CREATE USER 'php'@'mycomputer.mshome.net' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: Does the user I created on the server computer?

Comment: I don't understand your last question

Comment: On computer server or computer client when i create user ?

Comment: Create the user from server computer, using phpMyAdmin or MySQL command prompt.